# How can I associate a type with a number

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I want to be able to generate a number for each type of a particular typelist.

i.e. for the following 2 typelists (where `Group` works like std::variant):

```cpp
class myclass;

using GroupA = Group<int, double, myclass>;

static_assert( GroupA::type_number<int> == 0 );
static_assert( GroupA::type_number<double> == 1 );
static_assert( GroupA::type_number<myclass> == 2 );


using GroupB = Group<double, myclass>;  // different group => different numbering

static_assert( GroupB::type_number<double> == 0 );
static_assert( GroupB::type_number<myclass> == 1 );
```

I tried to recurse through the `Types`, but I cannot end up with one template parameter on every `type`

```cpp
template < typename ... Types> 
struct Group
{
    
    template < typename T > 
    constexpr static int type_number = 0;
    
    template < typename T, typename ... Types >
    constexpr static int type_number = type_number<Types...> + 1;

};
```

I am imitating `any`/`variant` and I want to be able to sort a vector of them.

Comment: There are a number of fundamental C++ reasons why this is un-possible. Especially if you want a `constexpr` `type_number`. Just conduct a simple thought experiment yourself. Put two of these types in different header files. No translation unit `#include`s both of them. Or they are `#include`d in different order. How do you expect to achieve a consistent `type_number` for each one of the two types?

Comment: How should sorting work for incomparable types?

Comment: Note that [`std::type_index`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) might be the best tool here

Comment: @alterigel, good idea, but I need something that will work the same way between different compilers/operating systems. I think `type_info` does not guarantee that, does it?

Comment: @alterigel, (about sorting between incomparable types) : I plan to make a vector of type-erased objects, sharing a `get_type_number()` function. I will sort it using this type_number first. If they are the same type, I can then compare them the normal way.

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines:

```
template <typename T, typename Head, typename ... Tail>
constexpr int TypeNumber(int start) {
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, Head>) {
    return start;
  } else {
    return TypeNumber<T, Tail...>(start + 1);
  }
}

template < typename ... Types> 
struct Group
{
    template < typename T > 
    constexpr static int type_number = TypeNumber<T, Types...>(0);
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fM6vfW7Go)

Comment: (+1) For C++11 I replaced `std::is_same_v<T,Head>`  with `std::is_same<T,Head>::value`. But C++11 does not have `constexpr if`. Should I use the ternary operator (pred?true:false) to get around this?

Comment: Ternary operator won't work, since both halves of it get instantiated (ask me how I know). In C++11, you'd need partial specialization. In any case, C++11 doesn't have template variables, so you can't have `GroupA::type_number<int>` syntax to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive way make code longer to compile.
Trick is to use pairing from the start,

Then, you can use overload to "select" the `Pair` by index or by type (doublon would cause ambiguous call).

```
template <typename T, std::size_t I>
struct Pair
{
   // possibly data, as `T data;` for tuple
};

template <typename T, std::size_t I>
constexpr std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I> type_number(Pair<T, I>) { return {}; }

template <typename Seq, typename ... Ts>
struct GroupImpl;

template <std::size_t ... Is, typename ... Ts>
struct GroupImpl<std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ts...> : Pair<Ts, Is>...
{
    template <typename T>
    constexpr static auto type_number() { return decltype(::type_number<T>(GroupImpl{})){}; }

};

template <typename ... Ts>
using Group = GroupImpl<std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>, Ts...>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ff823fa4cb08536)

`std::index_sequence` is not C++11, but can be implemented in C++11
(linearly or even logarithmically in number of instantiation) (in C++14, in std, compiler might even use intrinsic to have only one instantiation :-) )